# Browser caching images from ASP.NET Handler with complex URL not working

Tags: asp.net, webforms, browser-cache, httphandler

I'm trying to cache images, which are provided using a ASP.NET Handler same code as below:

**Handler**

```
public class ResourceHandler : IHttpHandler, IRouteHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
        context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));

        RouteData routeData = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;

        string name = routeData.Values["type"].ToString();
        string imagePath = "path/{type}"

        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(imagePath);

        if (fileInfo == null)
        {
            // Resource not found
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            return;
        }

        string rawIfModifiedSince = context.Request.Headers.Get("If-Modified-Since");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawIfModifiedSince))
        {
            // Set Last Modified time
            context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime ifModifiedSince = DateTime.Parse(rawIfModifiedSince);

            // HTTP does not provide milliseconds, so remove it from the comparison
            if (fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.AddMilliseconds(
                               -fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc.Millisecond) == ifModifiedSince)
            {
                // The requested file has not changed
                context.Response.StatusCode = 304;
                return;
            }
        }

        using (Stream stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
            while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, 32) > 0)
            {
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

}

**Routes**

I figure out that the route complexity was forcing the browser to always request from the server, never from the cache. (I've tried many, Chrome, Firefox, Edge)

If I register a simple route, everything works as intended:

```
routes.Add(new Route("image/{type}", new ResourceHandler()));
```

Example:

> http://localhost/image/CompanyLogo/f8d8c2cc-271c-407e-9bbb-3deae1c577da_f8d8c2cc-271c-407e-9bbb-3deae1c577da_9bc61578-6c05-4532-8dce-ed2d6e28e8fc?size=normal&d=02102018061450

But Every browser refuses to get an image from cache if the url is like this:

```
routes.Add(new Route("image/{type}/{authenticatedUserId}/{userId}/{imageid}", new ResourceHandler()));
```

Example:

> http://localhost/image/CompanyLogo/f8d8c2cc-271c-407e-9bbb-3deae1c577da/f8d8c2cc-271c-407e-9bbb-3deae1c577da/9bc61578-6c05-4532-8dce-ed2d6e28e8fc?size=normal&d=02102018061450

I've tried every possible header in combination, but why is the URL the issue? The simple one works, the dynamic one doesn't.

**UPDATE**

It works with the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: If the url changes then it's not got a reference for the cache, so will go to the server. If you were to append the current datetime to the url as a query string you would see the same behaviour.

Comment: @SeanT the URL never changes, I'm providing a static file from the handler just to hide my storage. (GDPR things)

Comment: ah ok I get you, just threw me with dynamic route!

Comment: The route is dynamic, but for the same image, which is already cached, it shouldn't request again, the whole point is why!

Comment: If your route is dynamic, then it's going to change depending on the request is what I'm saying. Fair enough if you're making a request that always has the same values (same type, authenticateduserId, userId, imageId) but if these chnage then it won't look at cache

Comment: @SeanT thats is not my case, Is the Route, I've tried with smaller ones, and It works. Deeper the path, crazier the bug.